# How to Insert Page Info on Email Form?

Tags: forms, magento-1, contact-us, template-directive

I'm using the same form for a few pages.

> {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}

Is it possible to somehow detect from which page the email was sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the form.phtml file, add an extra hidden field and output the url if you like.

Get the URL with this:

```
<?php
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
$path = $url->getPath();
?>
```

Place the above php code above the first line of html code in your

```
app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/contacts/form.phtml
```

Somewhere within the `<form> </form>` tag insert a hidden field and output the $url variable (here it's based on the rwd theme):

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $path; ?>" />
```

So, the complete form.phtml looks like this:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Magento
     *
     * NOTICE OF LICENSE
     *
     * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
     * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
     * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
     * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
     * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
     * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
     * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
     *
     * DISCLAIMER
     *
     * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
     * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
     * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
     *
     * @category    design
     * @package     rwd_default
     * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
     * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
     */
    ?>
    <?php
        $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
        $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
        $path = $url->getPath();
    ?>
    <div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></h1>
    </div>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" class="scaffold-form">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
            <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="tel" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-set">
            <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
            <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $path; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Here is how to add the extra field (and show it in the transaction email): http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/contacts/add_fields_to_contact_form

Now add your Variable to your email template, following the above guide:

```
Sent from: {{var data.url}}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie. How do I create a hidden field? Which specific code?
And in which file do I add this: 
`$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
$path = $url->getPath();`

Comment: I've edited my answer for you ;)

Comment: `style="display:none !important;"` does not make the field hidden, it hides it, at most. Why don't you use `<input type="hidden" />` instead ?

Comment: You're right. I was in a hurry and it was quick and dirty hack, simply duplicating the existing `<input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />` which is in the template already. To be fair, anyone messing with the template .phtml files should have some basic grasp of html.